# What is the best way to use git with Django?

Tags: python, django, git

I'm starting with python and Django development and I'm creating a project that I want to share it with git. When I started the app I saw folders like "local", "lib", "bin", and "include". Should I ignore this folders or can I commit it?
There's a .gitignore "master" to django files? I found some files on google but any of them mentioned this folders.

Comment: Those don't sound like Django folders. Those sound like [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) folders.

Comment: I'm not using virtualenv anymore. Can I delete these folders?

Comment: Presumably. You're using git, so if you delete something that breaks your project, you can always restore it, right?

Comment: Hmm. If I were moving more slowly, I might have gone for "too broad" rather than "opinion-based".

Answer (score 2):

When doing Django development in Git you'll typically want to exclude *.db files, *.pyc files, your virtualenv directory, and whatever files your IDE and OS may create (eg: DS_store, *.swp, *.swo)